# How to replace linefeeds with SED by ignoring exceptions?

Tags: shell, awk, sed, linefeed

Hi I have the following CSV input data which features several newline and carriage return characters. I am trying to cleanup the file with SED:

```
"Data1","This<LF>
Is<LF>
Foobar"<CR><LF>
"Data2","Additional<LF>
Data<CR><LF>
With Inline CR LF<CR><LF>
End of Data."<CR><LF>
```

**Note:** CR and LF equals actual \r and \n here

I want to replace all linefeeds which have no prepended " - the double quoted character is imported here to consider. I manage to filter out all linefeeds but do not know how to tell SED to ignore those with a specific pattern.

Output is expected to look like this:

```
"Data1","This Is Foobar"
"Data2","Additional Data With Inline CR LF End of Data."
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the expected output

Comment: DO you have literal `<CR>` and `<LF>` or `\n, \r` etc?

Comment: We are talking about actual linefeeds and carriage returns: \n \r

Comment: sed reads one line at a time and chops off the newline before putting what's left into the pattern space.  Thus to replace newlines it's kinda not really good for that. [It seems possible though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed). Awk is better for this, but sadly awk  doesn't seem to support negative lookbehind. But even without lookbehinds it could be done via a capture group `([^\"])\r?\n` change to `\1 `.

Comment: @EdMorton Wait, is that not what they wanted... I don't think i understood the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `gnu awk` as you have `\r` instead of `<CR>` and `\n` instead of `<LF>` shown in question:

```
awk -v BINMODE=3 -v RS='"\r\n"' 's!=""{printf "%s\"\n\"", s} {
   s = $0; gsub(/\r?\n/, " ", s)} END{print s}' file

"Data1","This Is Foobar"
"Data2","Additional Data Width Inline CR LF End of Data."
```

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for the tips. I've corrected the awk command now to take care of `"foo","<CR><LF>bar"` input as well

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="\"[^\"]*\"" }
RT != "" {
    gsub(/\r/,"")
    gsub(/[\r\n]+/," ",RT)
    printf "%s%s", $0, RT
}
END { print "" }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"Data1","This Is Foobar"
"Data2","Additional Data With Inline CR LF End of Data."
```